# My HTML element stops responding once I introduce a media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an `h1` element with an id of `iAbout`. I have created space above the element by adding `padding-top: 50px;` I am working on making my website responsive by using

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

Now I know my media query works because when I edit other elements via using ids and classes I have no problem. But for some reason when I edit this specific element under the media query it doesn't work. But if I edit the element outside of the query it works just fine. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post your css/html - http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Comment: try to make http://jsfiddle.net/ of the question, it would make it very easy to answer the question

Comment: I'm trying but it's not loading correctly.

Comment: @FLF: Your "formatting" is worse than no formatting at all. Please avoid suggesting such edits again in the future.

Comment: @BoltClock so whats is unique in your formatting.